# bundle exec rake assets:precompile - keeps failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku through nitrious.io.  It keeps failing when i try to use git to commit to heroku.  I have searched a lot and tried a lot of different things and none work.  One promising angle was running the bundle exec (as that's where the roll out to heroku fails) first and then trying to commit to heroku.  This is the output when i run the bundle exec and i don't know enough to figure out where the error is.  Any help would be awesome.  The first one is the first run, the second block of code is with the trace.

> ```
> > action@markruby-146191:~/workspace/learn-rails(master*)$ bundle exec
> > rake assets:precompile                                                
> > rake aborted!                                                         
> > NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for
> > #<LearnRails::Application:0x00000004b8ce88>                                                                                                                                                                                  /home/action/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:1:in
> > `<top (required)>'                                                    
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in
> > `require'                                                             
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in
> > `block in require'                                                    
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in
> > `load_dependency'                                                     
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in
> > `require'                                                             
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in
> > `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'                                  
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in
> > `each'                                                                
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in
> > `block in <class:Engine>'                                             
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> > `instance_exec'                                                       
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> > `run'                                                                 
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
> > `block in run_initializers'                                           
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
> > `each'                                                                
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
> > `tsort_each_child'                                                    
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
> > `run_initializers'                                                    
> > /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in
> > `initialize!'                                                         
> > /home/action/workspace/learn-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top
> > (required)>'
> ```

This is the output when i use the trace

```
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'                                                                                                                                                                                      
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'                                                                                                                                                                                   
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'                                                                                                                                                           
/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'                                                                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'                                                                                                                                                                    
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'                                                                                                                                                             
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'                                                                                                                                                                                      
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'                                                                                                                                                                      
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'                                                                                                                                                           
/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'                                                                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'                                                                                                                                                                    
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'                                                                                                                                                                                    
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'                                                                                                                                                                        
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'                                                                                                                                                      
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'                                                                                                                                                                               
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'                                                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'                                                                                                                                                                   
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'                                                                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'                                                                                                                                                                        
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'                                                                                                                                                        
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'                                                                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                                                                                   
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/rake:23:in `load'                                                                                                                                                                                                                
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'                                                                                                                                                                                                              
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'                                                                                                                                                                                               
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: 587,
domain: ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"],
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
  # Send email in development mode.
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module LearnRails
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # For Foundation 5
    #config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/modernizr )
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false


  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your intializers/development.rb and intializers/production.rb change line "Rails.application.configure" to "LearnRails::Application.configure" 
In environment.rb change this one "Rails.application.initialize!"  with "LearnRails::Application.initialize!" 
Add/uncomment "config.assets.enabled = true" in application.rb

Comment: This is on line 5 of environment.rb

Rails.application.initialize!

i'll attach the requested files to the original question.

Thanks for the response@!

Comment: also, and excuse my limited knowledge, how did you know the error was in environment.rb?  Just let me know the line that points to it..i was looking and couldn't see anything that directed me to the error. Thanks! :)

Comment: # Enable the asset pipeline
Let the heroku to precomile assets, put follwing in application.rb
config.assets.enabled = true

And remove file public/assets/manifest.yml or public/assets/manifest-<md5 hash>.json
Also take a look at following links for asset pipline:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: okay, i enabled the asset pipeline by adding that line to application.rb.   There was no manifest.yml in my public folder..or am i missing something? (also, no /assets/ in my public folder)

Comment: I have updated the answer, follow the steps and try to deploy on heroku.

Comment: i updated my environment.rb and commented out the line in application.rb.  The production.rb and development.rb don't exist in initilizers.  Still didn't work.  The trace looks the same but ends with "Tasks: TOP => environment  ".  It did not deploy to heroku.